# What is the way to set X-Frame options in react app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, clickjacking

I've build a react app using `create-react-app`. But then I came to know that my react app is open for clickjacking attack as I didn't set any X-Frame options in my app. Now how can I set X-Frame options in my react app which is created my `create-react-app` and I have no express js backend.

Answer (score -1):

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/headers

You could try this...I hope it works

```
 async headers() {
return [
  {
    // source: "/login",
    headers: [
      {
        key: "X-Content-Options",
        value: "Deny",
      },
      {
        key: "Content-Security-Policy",
        value: "frame-ancestors 'none'",
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

},